# DialogInterface (yes/no) inside another dialoginterface

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hello :) I want to make a DialogInterface for buying more coins, and if you press no, It will open another DialogInterface that will ask are you sure?
here is my code so far:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    //Yes button clicked
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage("Do you want to buy more coins?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();       
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to buy more coins?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();               
        }
```

My problem is, at one of the lines:
" `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` "
 I get an error  `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`

Can someone fix it to me ? TY :)

### FIXED

HERE is the solvement:

To anyone with the same problem, change the line

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

to:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(XXX.this);`

`XXX`=Your current `class`(`mainactivity`,`firstactivity`,`shop` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to the current context, which in the internal case is the `OnClickListener` itself (and which is not a valid context for the function).

You need to somehow refer to the external activity context referred to as `this` in the first `Builder`. Try setting a `context` field in your activity's `onCreate()` method as follows:

```
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  context = this;
```

Then, you can refer to this inside the `OnClickListener` as

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Ty, you idea is working too, anyway, look the edit, you can also change this to `classname.this`

Comment: Any way, I can't except answers because my low reputation, only in more 8 minutes, I will accept it, I can't vote up until I will get 15 rep..